# Using gpg to digitally sign an encrypted key

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa, gnupg

I'm working on a lab for my computer security class, and one step is giving me problems.  [Here is the assignment.](http://pastebin.com/6RhEuK4A) [And here is all the work I've done up until step 11.](http://pastebin.com/QBAJbaEi)  It is step 11 that I am having trouble with.

```
11.  Use gpg and your own private RSA key to digitally sign aes.key.asc.
Digital signature must be appendedto cipher and stored in
key_signed.txt
```

The problem is that when I do the following command

```
gpg --sign -o key_signed.txt -a aes.key.asc
```

Expected output (by assignment):

[image: Example output]

My output instead looks like this:

```
root@bt:~/lab2# cat key_signed.txt 
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.10 (GNU/Linux)
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=ZfM8
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I think I just need to use the `>>` stream redirection operator to append the signature to the encryption but everything I have tried doesn't result in something that starts with

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

What to do to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your expected output, as near as I can tell the assignment is asking you to "clear sign" the encrypted file.  So try this command:

```
gpg --clearsign -o key_signed.txt aes.key.asc
```

I found [this pretty good reference](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/gpg/gpg-com-4.htm) that might be helpful.  There are many others available if you do a web search.

Comment: Oh just realized you were faster by a few seconds. :) `-a` isn't neccessary, `--clearsign` always gives ascii output.

Comment: @JensErat Good catch.  Another case of my "cut-and-paste" sloppiness.  I'll revise.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at GnuPG's `--clearsign` flag. From man pages:

```
   --clearsign
          Make a clear text signature.  The content in a clear text signature is read-
          able without any special software. OpenPGP software is only needed to verify
          the signature.  Clear text signatures may modify end-of-line whitespace  for
          platform  independence and are not intended to be reversible.  The key to be
          used for signing is chosen by default or can be set  with  the  --local-user
          and --default-key options.
```

Use this command to get expected output:

```
gpg --clearsign -o key_signed.txt aes.key.asc
```